# The type 'typename' exists in both App_Code.dll and solution.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution which includes a Web Application Project plus a number of Class Library Projects. The solution builds successfully in VS but when I browse to an ASPX page I get this error:

```
Compilation Error

S0433: The type '<type-name>' exists in both
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
Files\root\3e98edf3\c4c22795\App_Code.dll' and
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
Files\root\3e98edf3\c4c22795\assembly\dl3\ef67a753\a19c0f5f_801ecf01\
my-solution.DLL
```

My Web Application project does not contain an App_Code folder, only an AppCode (note the missing underscore) folder.  I inherited this project from another developer so can't find out why it is setup this way.

I have tried clearing my temporary ASP.net files and have Cleaned and Rebuilt the solution.

Comment: Check the bin folder of your app to see if there are both dlls existing. (App_Code.dll and my-solution.DLL)

Comment: There were 2 files: App_SubCode_WSCSCode.dll and App_SubCode_WSVBCode.dll.  I deleted both and reloaded my ASPX page - same error.  I Build the Web App again and the files are re-created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem! When viewing through Windows Explorer, I had an AppCode and an App_Code folder with the same files in each.  I guess whoever worked on this before me had created AppCode and somewhere along the way the new App_Code was added.

This is what caused the duplicate type name, one compiled into App_Code.dll and the other into solution.dll

Comment: So, what did you do solve this problem. I get the same error now. But can't understand how to fix it. I'm almost newbie at C#